# How do I accomplish Drupal "double gzip" prevention in Nginx?

Tags: nginx, .htaccess, gzip, drupal, drupal7

There is this section of the default .htaccess that Drupal ships with:

```
# Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]
```

I am not experienced with Drupal but in other projects with Nginx as the web server, I have never had a "double-gzip" issue.

How necessary is it, and what is the best nginx directive to accomplish this?

Note: I also posted this question to drupal.stackexchange.com, but I feel like it is not necessarily a Drupal specific issue, so I posted it here as well.

Comment: Please do not cross-post. Questions should have one authoritative community.

Comment: Well maybe you can help me decide which community should be the authoritative community. It is an nginx configuration issue that isn't necessarily specific to drupal. However, it is also something that drupal users would be more interested in than the average nginx user. Since it is an Nginx/Apache issue at the root and the community here is bigger, I am guessing here is the best place, but your criticism is welcome.

Comment: I guess, you should read about gzip_static module

Comment: @AlexeyTen I guess you should point out the part of that module's manual page that shows how to prevent "double gzip".